# Compile source code error expected pragma

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging

I am getting an error when coding a token with the Ethereum wallet. Namely, Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition. function burn (uint256 _value)public returns(bool success) {

could anyone help me with this error, as i am not sure what is really missing,[image] in this line of code.

Comment: The issue is likely before that line of code. Can you edit your question to include all of the contract code, rather than just a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be 100% sure without the code, but it's consistent with closing out the `contract {}` block with an extra `}` so that `function` is outside of it where it should not be. Out there, you're only allowed `pragma`, `contract`, `library`, etc. as enumerated in the message.

Look for an extra `}` after the function before the section shown.

Hope it helps.